# Does Edmonds Karp take back-edges into account?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

I amb doubting with the implementation of the Edmonds-Karp implementation of the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.

This is a problem with flow networks.

As I understand the algorithm, it consists on taking a path from s to t (randomly in Ford-Fulkerson, and a shortest path in Edmonds-Karp) and saturate the bottleneck for that path. That adds back-edges that allow to "reconduct" the flow. The bottleneck for that path is added to the maximum flow and the algorithm runs until there is no such "augmenting" path.

I'm doubtful, though, with the back-edges role in all this.

Should I take back edges into consideration when finding such shortest path? Most implementations I've found don't take that into account.

If so, how would I treat them, because as I understand it, taking a back edge means reconducting the flow, and thus I should subtract some quantity from the maximum flow shouldn't I?

Comment: "Most implementations I've found don't take that into account." -- Of course they do! Note that finding the augmenting path is done on the *residual* network in which "back edges" are just normal edges. (Your understanding in the last paragraph is correct. See a textbook for examples why this is necessary, and the augmenting path theorem.)